# Merge array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I want to join two hashes like database tables and merge them in to one hash.
I have 2 array of hashes like the following:

Hash 1:

```
classrooms = [{"id"=>4, "title"=>"Class A"}]
```

Hash 2:

```
teacher_lessons = [{"program_day"=>1, "bell"=>1, "lesson_id"=>1, "classroom_id"=>4},
 {"program_day"=>1, "bell"=>2, "lesson_id"=>3, "classroom_id"=>4},
 {"program_day"=>2, "bell"=>1, "lesson_id"=>4, "classroom_id"=>4}]
```

expected:

```
[{"program_day"=>1, "bell"=>1, "lesson_id"=>1, "classroom_id"=>4, "classroom_title"=> "Class A"},
 {"program_day"=>1, "bell"=>2, "lesson_id"=>3, "classroom_id"=>4, "classroom_title"=> "Class A"},
 {"program_day"=>2, "bell"=>1, "lesson_id"=>4, "classroom_id"=>4, "classroom_title"=> "Class A"}]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no attempt at solving the problem. No code was provided, working or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have many classrooms, I would transform classroom data first:

```
classrooms = [{"id" => 4, "title" => "Class A"}, 
              {"id" => 5, "title" => "Class B"}]
title_by_id = classrooms.map(&:values).to_h
#=> {4=>"Class A", 5=>"Class B"}
```

Then simply modify each hash, according to the "classroom_id" key:

```
teacher_lessons.each {|hash| hash["title"] = title_by_id[hash["classroom_id"]]}
#=>[{"program_day"=>1,"bell"=>1,"lesson_id"=>1,"classroom_id"=>4,"title"=>"Class A"},
#   {"program_day"=>1,"bell"=>2,"lesson_id"=>3,"classroom_id"=>4,"title"=>"Class A"},
#   {"program_day"=>2,"bell"=>1,"lesson_id"=>4,"classroom_id"=>4,"title"=>"Class A"}]
```

If you dont want to modify source object, use `map` + `merge`:

```
teacher_lessons.map {|h| h.merge("title" => title_by_id[h["classroom_id"]])}
```